# Decomposing into Gaussian components using Bhattacharya from topFishR

Tags: r, data-transformation, gaussian-mixture-distribution, bhattacharyya

I am working with fishery data. I have a data vector called `SFL` that contains the sizes of the fish caught. Here is some sample data:

```
# Two normal distributions
c1 <- rnorm(1000,2,0.5); c1 <- c1[c1 > 0]
c2 <- rnorm(1000,6,2); c2 <- c2[c2 > 0] 

# Sorted SFL vector
SFL <- sort(c(c1, c2))
```

Here my histogram:

```
# Histogram
hist(SFL, breaks = 20, prob=TRUE)
```

[image]

Now I need to decompose the SFL distribution of sizes into the different Gaussian components (in this case 2). I am interested in using the tropFishR package to apply the Bhattacharya method. According to the [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/TropFishR/html/Bhattacharya.html), the `Bhattacharya` function receives the following in the `param` argument:

- `midLengths` midpoints of the length class as vector.
- `catch` a vector with the catch per length class or a matrix with catches per length class of subsequent years.

How can I create the required vectors from my `SFL` vector?